# Backbonejs - How do I initialize the view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Somehow when I initialize my view I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined`

I have the following code:

```
//Model
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title: 'Red',
            artist: 'Taylor Swift',
            filename: 'audio1.mp3',
            playlist: 0
        },

}); 

//Collection
var Playlist = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Song,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('playlist'),
    initialize: function(models,options) {
        _.extend(this,_.pick(options, 'currentTrack'));
        this.fetch({ajaxSync: true})
    },
    url: 'metadata',
    parse: function(response){
        return response
    },
    currentTrack: 0,
    currentTime: 0
});

//View
var Player = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "audio",
        id: "player",
        model: playlist,
        currentSong: function(){
            console.log(this.model);
            return this.model.at(this.model.currentTrack).toJSON();
        },
        events: {
            'ended': 'next',
            'pause': 'saveTime'
        },
        newTemplate: _.template('<source src="<%= filename %>" >'),
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.newTemplate(this.currentSong()));
            $(document.body).html(this.el);
        },
        next: function(){
            if(this.model.length == this.model.currentTrack){
                console.log('End of the playlist');
            }
            else{
            this.model.currentTrack++;
            console.log('currentTrack: ', this.model.currentTrack);
            this.render();
            this.el.src = this.currentSong().filename;
            this.el.play();
            }
        },
        saveTime: function(){
            console.log('Saving currentTime:', this.el.currentTime);
            this.model.currentTime = this.el.currentTime;
        }
});


var playlist = new Playlist();
var player = new Player({model: playlist});
```

Somehow when I initialize the `player` view the `playlist` colleciton hasn't been populated yet. I can run `var player = new Player({model: playlist})` fine from console.

Comment: Most likely you need to listen for collection events and then render the view. If you debug, what variable is undefined? Also, `playlist` is a collection so it should be `collection: playlist`

Comment: It's this.model that returns undefined

Comment: `model: playlist,` in the view properties (in the `extend`) is useless. This is an option that is supposed to be passed on instantiation, like you do the at the bottom.

Comment: Alright. Changing it

Answer (score 1):

Your collection is empty. So `this.model.at(this.model.currentTrack);` which is actually `this.collection.at(0);` will return `undefined`. Hence you're executing `undefined.toJSON()`.

You need to put null checks here and wait for the collection data to be fetched before rendering.

And it is a good idea to pass the collection as `collection` instead of `model`

Comment: Yes it is empty at first, but I populate it with data from server using fetch. Where should the fetch method be called?

Comment: Or how can I tell the currentSong() method to wait for the fetched data?

Comment: @medicengonzo `this.fetch({success: function(){this.render();} })` or `this.fetch().then(function(){this.render(); })` or you can setup a listener to `sync` event and assign `render` as callback

Comment: @medicengonzo that was close 5sec difference between comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Before rendering I have to wait for the collection to be fetched as [T J said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671630/3440297)

He said to use

```
this.fetch({success: function(){ this.render }})
```

or

```
this.fetch().then(function(){ this.render });
```

but in the end I did it with

```
this.fetch().done(function(){ this.render() });
```